# what to do in the below program so as to eradicate the compiler error given below and make the program to work at it best?

Tags: java

The error displayed by the compiler is :-

"Slot_Machine is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener."

The Program is :-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Slot_Machine extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
public void init()
{
Button B1 = new Button("Start");
B1.addActionListener(this);
add(B1);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
int mm = 5000;
int x1[] = {245,210,210,245,315,350,350,315};
int y1[] = {175,315,385,525,525,385,315,175};
int n1 = x1.length;
int x2[] = {455,420,420,455,525,560,560,525};
int x3[] = {665,630,630,665,735,770,770,735};
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillPolygon(x1,y1,n1);
g.fillPolygon(x2,y1,n1);
g.fillPolygon(x3,y1,n1);
int x4[] = {280,245,315};
int y4[] = {210,280,280};
int n4 = x4.length;
int x5[] = {490,455,525};
int x6[] = {700,665,735};
int x7[] = {245,280,315};
int y7[] = {420,490,420};
int n7 = x7.length;
int x8[] = {455,490,525};
int x9[] = {665,700,735};
g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillPolygon(x4,y4,n4);
g.fillPolygon(x5,y4,n4);
g.fillPolygon(x6,y4,n4);
g.fillPolygon(x7,y7,n7);
g.fillPolygon(x8,y7,n7);
g.fillPolygon(x9,y7,n7);
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fillRect(245,315,70,70);
g.fillRect(455,315,70,70);
g.fillRect(665,315,70,70);
Font F1 = new Font ("courier new", Font.BOLD,20);
g.setFont(F1);
Button B1 = new Button ("Start");
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add implementation for `actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)`  in your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've marked the class as implementing the ActionListener interface, but you're not actually implementing it at all.

You have to have this method in your class

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awt/awt_action_listener.htm

Answer (score 0):

If it is supposed to be an `ActionListener` then you need to implement the `ActionListener` interface. Otherwise don't say that it is an `ActionListener`

either implement:

```
void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) {
  // stuff
}
```

or

```
public class Slot_Machine extends Applet
```